# Logstash : how to output a selection of fields

Tags: output, logstash

I have a logstash exe that read JSON events from a RabbitMQ queue.

```
input {
  rabbitmq  {
    codec => json
    ...
  }
}
```

I need to have 2 outputs. The first one is a MongoDB output with the entire JSON document (no problem, it works), and the second is another rabbitMQ queue but I don't need the entire JSON. I just need a selection of fields.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a `mutate` filter with a `remove_field` entry to remove all of the fields you don't want.  If you don't know what all of the fields are that you need to remove, you'll need to create a `ruby` filter the iterates over the event and removes anything that isn't in your desired list.

That ruby code would look something like this:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => " 
                event.to_hash.each {|k,v|
                        if (!['a','b','c'].include?(k))
                                event.remove(k)
                        end
                }"
    }
}
```

where `['a','b','c']` is the list of fields you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the following codec:  https://github.com/payscale/logstash-codec-fieldselect  It selects some fields for output.  Just like the above but without a ruby filter.